# How to print the text inside another ul tag using Selenium Java

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Guys I am on learning Selenium Automation.

I Designed a website as this below one.

My Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Shop</title></head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="www.rendertofruitsection.com">Fruits</a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="www.addbananatocart.com">» Banana</a></li>
           <li><a href="www.addappletocart.com">» Apple</a></li>
           <!--List goes on-->
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.redertovegsection">Vegetable</a>
         <ul>
              <li><a href="www.addcapcicumtocart">» Capsicum</a></li>
              <li><a href="www.addtomatotocart.com">» Tomato</a></li>
              <li><a href="www.addoniontocart">» Onion</a></li>
              <!--List goes on-->
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a herf="www.nonveglink.com">Non Veg Section</a></li>
    <!--List goes on-->
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Initially I planned to list out all the text presented inside `<a>` tag using java selenium.

So I wrote this code below.

My Java Code:

```
public class shop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.myshopping.com");
        List<WebElement> text=  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
        for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++)
        {
             System.out.println(i+". "+text.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Output What I got and needed:

```
 Output what I got:                      | Output What I need:
 1. Fruits                               | 1. Fruits
 2.                                      | 2. Banana
 3.                                      | 3. Apple
 4. Vegetable                            | 4. Vegetable
 5.                                      | 5. Capsicum
 6.                                      | 6. Tomato 
 7.                                      | 7. Onion
 8. Non Veg Section                      | 8. Non Veg Section
```

Guys just tell little hint ,how to get the text in inner `<ul>` its `<li>` tag using Selenium Java.

I tried this some what, But I Stuck up here.please help.

Thank you

Comment: This code gave me all the texts you are looking for. It also gave me numbers from 0 to 7. Please provide the ***exact*** code and output, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: `getAttribute("innerText")` works for my case. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list out all the text presented inside `<a>` tag you can try the following code block :

```
public class shop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("www.myshopping.com");
    List<WebElement> atags =  driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for(WebElement atag:atags)
         System.out.println("Text is : " + atag.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `getAttribute("innerText")` works for my case

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathOfTheElement"));
String text = x.getAttribute("innerText");
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: `getAttribute("innerText")` works for my case

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply outer loop for item types and add inner loop for items that seem to be generated dynamically:

```
public class shop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.myshopping.com");
        List<WebElement> text=  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[ul]/a"));
        for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++)
        {
             System.out.println(i+". "+text.get(i).getText());
             WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(i, 10);
             List<WebElement> innerText =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(".//following-sibling::ul//a[text()]")));
             for(int j=0; j<text.size(); j++)
             {
                 System.out.println(i+". "+j+". "+text.get(j).getText());
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getAttribute("innerText")` works for my case. But your wait.until is bit not understandable for this novice .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you meant only the items inside the outer `ul` then change the codes as follows. It's just a locator change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("file:///C:/Users/abdul%20awal/Desktop/test.html");
       List<WebElement> text=  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul ul a"));
       for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++)
       {
            System.out.println(i+". "+text.get(i).getText());
       }
   }
```

For CSS selector reference follow the link:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp